# LTspice filter giving same output voltage from every input voltage and frequency?

Tags: filter, ltspice, active-filter

I'm investigating different active filters using LTspice. I've done 3 different circuits of slightly different designs. With each circuit, I use LTspice transient analysis to check the output voltages over a range of frequencies, and use these voltages to produce a plot of the magnitude of the circuit.

With my first 2 circuits, this worked fine and all my calculations matched up correctly with the magnitude plot Ltspice gives from AC analysis.

I've now created a new circuit which introduces feedback (R4 and R5 in the image below) and now I'm getting this issue. No matter what input voltage or input frequency I use, the output is about 22.5V every single time. This is really confusing me. AC analysis of the circuit still produces a valid magnitude plot, but transient analysis is just not right. The only changes to the circuit is the feedback loop and different resistor values.

Is this a bug or have I done something wrong? And if its a bug can someone help me fix it as I need to finish this asap.

The circuit in question:

[image]

This is transient analysis with a 5V, 1kHz input. Output pk-pk voltage is 22.5V

[image]

And this is analysis using a 5V, 10kHz input. The output is different at first but then goes to 22.5V again.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried reducing the amplitude of Vin?

Comment: @vofa yes it is literally exactly the same at every amplitude and frequency

Comment: It looks like you went for a [multiple feedback bandpass](http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/OPtazyuBakeisan.htm), but then `R5` and `R4` cancel that, by bringing positive feedback, giving you the oscillator you currently have. If you want to modify the gain while keeping the multiple feedback topology, then you have to recalculate the existing negative feedback elements, not add others.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have build an oscillator. In general, you can enhance the selectivity (pole-Q) using positive feedback. This is a known modification as proposed by Deliyannis, long time ago. However, the pole-Q (selectivity) as well as the midband gain are both very sensitive to the ratio R4/R5. So you must be very careful during designing such a topology.

Working principle of "your oscillator": We have a fixed positive feedback and, at the same time, negative feedback which is very strong for (a) very small frequencies (resistive) and (b) for very large frequencies (capacitive). In between, there is a frequency which cannot override the positive feedback and which - at the same time - has zero phase shift. Hence, we have oscillation.

By the way: A "good" ac response (magnitude for small-signal analysis) is NEVER an indicator for stability. Only a TRAN analysis (time domain) can reveal stability properties (or a detailed loop gain analysis, applying a stability criterion)

Comment: You're right, I completely forgot about Deliyannis in my comment. However, it would help if OP let's us know what equations were used.

Answer (score 0):

You have an oscillator. the simulation shows it. Back to the drawing board. If the circuit is right the component values are wrongly selected. The exponential growth of the output is the typical startup in sinewave oscillators (=amplifier or filter circuit which have a s-domain complex pole in the positive half plane)

The output grows until the maximal opamp output voltage is reached. the oscillation frequency is quite high and the slowness of the opamp makes the output quite sinewave-like. With faster amp it would look more rectangular if the frequency happened to stay same.

In theory the oscillation also could have different frequency with different opamp or the circuit could even be stable because the transfer function of the opamp is a part of the oscillator loop.

ADD: You can try to increase R5 or decrease R4. The idea resembles radios in the era when direct receiver with positive feedback R.F. front stage (see NOTE1) was a good choice due its low cost, high selectivity and high gain. The user tuned the feedback setting at the edge of self oscillation. Unfortunately someone somewhere always put his receiver to oscillate and scrambled the signal unusable for others at least inside the same house.

NOTE1: more commonly known as "regenerative receiver" if the front stage was also tweaked to work simultaneously as an AM detector. The tweak = biased to amplify the sine half cycles substantially differently =>> Rectification without a separate diode detector.

Comment: The component values have all been chosen based on a carefully followed guide, and then I've also checked them using a couple of equations which they satisfy, so Im not sure what else to do if i have to start again. The opamp is supplied by +/-12V so is that whats causing it?

Comment: I wouldn't even try a circuit which has positive feedback to the + input with resistors. That makes the circuit notoriously sensitive to small component value or opamp property variations. Start by checking if you have swapped the inputs.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a choice about the feedback design as its uni work lol, so it has to be done this way. If you mean swapped the inputs to the op-amp, then no they are the same as the instructions tell me, and the same as the previous, correctly working circuits. Would you recommend trying a different op-amp or will that not change anything?

Comment: Then try with ideal opamp. It's well possible in simulation. Build a differential amplifier and increase it's gain  gradually.

Comment: OK guess I'll give that a go and see, thanks for helpign